# write a list or an array in a text file without bracket or other symbols

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an zipped array like this

```
a = [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]
```

I want save the first numbers as a single column in a text file like bellow

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

this is my code but the out put include brackets or comma

```
lista=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    listb.append(list(a[i][0:1]))

with open ('diz.dat','w') as f:
   for i in range(0,len(lista)):
     f.write(str(lista[i])+"   "+'\n')
```

the output file is like this

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
```

Comment: remove the ```list``` keyword and change to ```a[i][0]``` so instead of ```list(a[i][0:1])``` you should have just ```a[i][0]```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a for loop and a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) if you want to store the first numbers for use further down in your program so you have to iterate over `a` only once:

```
a = [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]
first_nums = [item[0] for item in a] 
with open('diz.dat', 'w') as file:
    for item in first_nums:
        file.write(f"{item}\n")
```

**diz.dat:**

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Or more optimially as suggested by [u/Deepspace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1453822/deepspace) in the comments if you do not need to store the first numbers for use later in your program:

```
a = [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]
with open('diz.dat', 'w') as file:
    for item in a:
        file.write(f"{item[0]}\n")
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you (and OP) even bother to iterate the list twice. Just do `for item in a: f.write(f'{item[0]}\n')`

Answer (score 0):

Without even list comprehension:

```
a = [(1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)]

with open ('diz.dat','w') as f:
    for num in a:
        f.write(f"{[num[0]]}\n")
```

**OUTPUT (diz.dat)**:

```
[1]   
[2]   
[3]   
[4]   
[5]
```

Comment: @DirtyBit the output is wrong. OP doesn't want the brackets.

Comment: @pault it does look it, if not it can be omitted by excluding the square brackets in the print statement. Cheers